# how to add third party angular directives to meteor application

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm using angular-meteor library to develop a meteor application with angular as a front-end.

I need to add an angular directive called angular-file-upload.

When I use this directive in my node/angular app, it is installed via bower, and has this folder structure:

```
    angular-file-upload folder contains 

angular-file-upload.js 
as well as a sub-folder named src,
 which contains 3 files: 

intro.js, module.js and outro.js
```

What is the process of installing such third party angular directives?

Is this done with meteor add command, or by placing these files manually into specific directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [link](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=angular-file-upload), if those are the actual packages which serve your purpose then you can directly add them to you Meteor app by using `meteor add <package-name>` command in the terminal.

While the alternate way to do this is by adding these `.js` files manually to `public` or `lib` folder and link them to your corresponding HTML pages. But I would personally prefer the 1st way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the library by yourself. There are few alternatives to do that.

Basically it goes down to these steps:

- add `package.js` in root directory
- `meteor publish --create`

The complete details how to do that can be found here: http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial/step_19

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: sure I will add that.